# not sure about my regelur expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I always get stucked with the `preg_match` function.

I want the input to match with `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `@#&-_.,` and nothing else.
So if `!` is in the input, it need to return false.

What I have till now.

```
$string = "String-20";
return (preg_match("/[a-z][A-Z][0-9][@#&-_.,]/i", $string)) ? true : false;
```

This should return `true`.

But keep return `false`.

Comment: Well, your regex matches 4 chars: 2 letters, then a digit and some chars including uppercase letters. You seem to want `/^[a-zA-Z0-9@#&_.,-]+$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to have those as one set rather than breaking them up like that. Your pattern would match a string like "aA0@"

You're saying "One character a-z, then one A-z, then one 0-9, then one of these special characters" but what you actually want is "Any number of these specific characters"

The ^ and $ mean start and end of the string so I think this should do what you want.

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@#&\-_.,]*$/i', $string)
```

Comment: Nice explenation. but when I remove the A-Z and have a uppercase in the string it still says true

Comment: Yeah my initial answer was totally wrong, try the edit <3

Comment: Also the ? true : false is kind of redundant, return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9@#&-_.,]*$/i', $string);

Comment: @ChickenWing1996: So you also want to accept a string that has `[` or ``\`` in it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No i dont

Comment: @ChickenWing1996: Then why did you accept this answer? See http://ideone.com/Tq1sko

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it wont be accepted, well it doesnt by me. so i ye :S

Comment: The `^` and `$` do not mean start and end of the *line*, but the start and end of the *string* (if `/m` modifier is not passed).

Comment: Wiktor, you're totally right here, and I'm just trying to understand why mine even matches the square brackets, could you explain or point me to something that would?

Comment: @BrettHarris: I explained everything in my answer. The hyphen may create a range inside a character class, and it did in this case. Since the range is valid, there was no error, but what is matched is not what is expected.

Comment: Edited so it's not totally wrong, I'd delete it if I could. Wiktor totally deserves the cred here.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches 4 character chunk(s) *anywhere* inside a string (as `preg_match` can find *partial matches*): 2 letters, then a digit and some chars including uppercase letters because `&-_` declares the following range:

[image]

Use

```
/^[a-z0-9@#&_.,-]+$/i
```

or even (since `\w` here will match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`):

```
/^[\w@#&.,-]+$/
```

If an empty string is allowed, replace `+` (one or more occurrences) with `*` (zero or more occurrences).

The `^` anchor will make sure the engine starts matching at the beginning of the string and `$` anchor will make sure the pattern should match up to the string end. The hyphen at the end of the character class will be parsed as a literal `-`.

Comment: Hyphen`-` whithin character class `[ ]` has special meaning of a range unless if it is escaped `\-` or the last character.